# What are common pitfalls when using @Embedded and @EmbeddedOnly in DataNucleus?

Tags: persistence, datanucleus

With JDO in RDBMS, I regularly get unexpected results (for me, anyway) when using the `@Embedded` or `@EmbeddedOnly` annotations. Usually, I end up removing the tags because of error messages.

Some of the messages are, paraphrased and partially:

1. Persistent class [...] has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
2. org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference cannot be cast to org.datanucleus.identity.OID

What are common pitfalls when using embedding tags in a hierarchy of objects? Do I have to avoid certain cascading operations—such as replacing an embedded child object entirely when updating?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get unexpected results in all of my tests and neither does the JDO TCK when using standards-compliant metadata (whether XML or annotations) in JDO. All DN testcases and the JDO TCK are public. Since you don't show some problem then I suggest that you review those public tests and see what is different in yours and from that you have your answer